# Kotlin via a Gradle build script isn't executing a WebDriver spek

Tags: gradle

Repo with a tight reproduction of my problem: https://github.com/paul-hammant/kotlin-webdriver-snafu

The spec, that could not be simpler:

```
class WebDriverSpeks : Spek({
    ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup()
    val co = ChromeOptions()
    val chromeDriver = ChromeDriver(co) as WebDriver

    beforeGroup {
        chromeDriver.get("https://yahoo.com/")    
    }

    describe("yahoo") {
        it("should have index.html") {
            assertEquals(chromeDriver.title, "hello")
        }    
    }

    afterGroup {
        chromeDriver.close()
    }
})
```

There's no red lines denoting compile failures in Intellij, yet when the `gradle build` runs it complains about a transitive dep:

```
$ gradle build
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.24/slf4j-    api-1.7.24.jar
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    /Users/paul/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.2.30/f916048adc012c9342b796a5f84c0ac6205abcac/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.2.30.jar (version 1.2)
    /Users/paul/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.2.30/ca12c47fc1e3a7316067b2a51e2f214745ebf8c5/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.2.30.jar (version 1.2)
    /Users/paul/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.0.6/3d499d3b7768f88c4796e5a1e357933e11a8936d/kotlin-reflect-1.0.6.jar (version 1.0)
    /Users/paul/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.2.30/2dfac33f8b4e92c9dd1422cd286834701a6f6d6/kotlin-stdlib-1.2.30.jar (version 1.2)
w: Consider providing an explicit dependency on kotlin-reflect 1.2 to prevent strange errors
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-runtime-version-check' to suppress this warning
e: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver, unresolved supertypes:    org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileTestKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
```

The allegedly unresolved supertype org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver is in a selenium-remote-driver, and

If I delete ~/.gradle or ./build and try again it is the same.

If I inspect the pom.xml for selenium-java, I can see a dependency on selenium-remote-driver (which exists). See here - http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-java/3.11.0/selenium-java-3.11.0.pom. The one in jcenter is the same.

I don't know why Gradle isn't finding selenium-remote-driver. I have an extra testCompile commented out in the Gradle script but nothing gets fixed if it is commented in.

I think this is a problem in Gradle, or some Gradleized treatment of Maven Central that I don't know much about but is online somewhere.  I don't think it is a Kotlin problem. I've used Selenium since it started and am super familiar with it (I've made 100 Maven projects that use Selenium) so I don't think that is it. Of course, I could be wrong with where the root cause is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this did the trick:

```
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/
```

I didn't know Gradle used the local Maven repo cache. It must have been corrupt somehow.

Hopefully this helps someone another day.